# OWIN - How to validate bearer token for roles after its returned by Auth Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, jwt, owin

I have been battling with security on our MVC apps for two weeks. I have set up an Authorization Server to generate tokens to be used by two client MVC applications. However, I am now generating the token and it returns a bearer token to the client, however where I check for a claim, it returns false.

This the code generating the token from Auth server:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        User user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The email address or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(context, user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

This generates the token to be sent to a client and in the 'GenerateUserIdentityAsync' method, I add the roles as required on the Claim Identity.

However, when I receive this on the client, the bearer token and do not know how to transform this into a local ClaimIdentity I can interogate to gain access to the roles. This is the code to get an access_token to the Resource Server (Client) from Auth Server:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SignIn(AccountViewModel account)
    {
        var getTokenUrl = $"{_settings.AuthServiceUrl}oauth2/token";

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", account.Login.Email),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", account.Login.Password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", _settings.AuthClientId)
        });
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = client.PostAsync(getTokenUrl, content).Result;

            string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(resultContent);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.access_token))
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Incorrect Username or Password, Please try again!";
                return View("Login");
            }

            var options = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(int.Parse(token.expires_in))
            }; 

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, account.Login.Email),
                new Claim("AccessToken", $"Bearer {token.access_token}"),
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(options, identity);

            if (identity.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

I have check the bearer token on JWT.io and it has the role:

> {
>     "nameid": "1",
>     "unique_name": [
>       "admin@fsa.co.za",
>       "Admin Admin"
>     ],
>     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider": "ASP.NET Identity",
>     "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp": "de9090f4-bddb-4baf-a62b-38ed0d6528fe",
>     "role": [
>       "Admin",
>       "Admin"
>     ],
>     "UserId": "1",
>     "sub": "admin@fsa.co.za",
>     "email": "admin@fsa.co.za",
>     "Verified": "False",
>     "iss": "https://localhost:44318/",
>     "aud": "b77f169bd7bf4787b1aed11599861768",
>     "exp": 1540293963,
>     "nbf": 1540292163
>   }

The question I have is, how do you on the client work with the bearer token and authorize users? How do you request a refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out. Essentially I need to work with Identity's JWT library to get the claims.

1. Need to install Nuget **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** package, which I already had
2. In order to get the claims back form the JWT Access Token, I needed on line which is in the code below:

---

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = client.PostAsync(getTokenUrl, content).Result;

    string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(resultContent);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.access_token))
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Incorrect Username or Password, Please try again!";
        return View("Login");
    }

    var options = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        AllowRefresh = true,
        IsPersistent = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(int.Parse(token.expires_in))
    }; 

    /*var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, account.Login.Email),
        new Claim("AccessToken", $"Bearer {token.access_token}"),
    };*/

    //JwtSecurityToken returns all the properties from the token service
    var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(token.access_token);
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims,  DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,ClaimTypes.Name,ClaimTypes.Role);
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(options, identity);

    if (identity.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
}
```